# image exist in folder but not displaying yii2 advanced

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Windows 10 and trying on my local. From backend, I am able to successfully upload image in backend/web/uploads folder and on frontend I tried to access via following code in gridview.

```
['attribute'=>'manufacturer_logo', 'label'=>'Logo', 'format' => 'html', 'value'=>function ($searchModel, $index, $widget) { return Html::img(Url::to('@web/uploads/' . $searchModel->manufacturer_logo),['width' => '50px']); }],
```

When I see image path from console then path looks like

> /myprojectname/backend/web/uploads/home_page_default_image.png

I also tried path with http like

> http://localhost/myprojectname/backend/web/uploads/home_page_default_image.png

but image is not showing, it is present in the folder, I am not able to find out what is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. So, a short checklist:

1. Verify that the file exist
2. Try the URL to the file directly on browser, the image have to appear. If not check permissions but as you are on windows, I don't think this to be the issue.
3. You don't need to use Url::to inside Html::img. This one knows how to interpret @web alias

Remember, you save with path but to show you need to use url. So, you need to make sure you are pointing to the same location.

And this one here is the behavior we created to forget about upload issues. https://github.com/daxslab/yii2-uploader-behavior.

Comment: I cross-checked and everything is fine that you mentioned, when I open Image URL then it opens home page of website.  I verified that image exists in folder and name is also correct

Comment: Well, if it opens home page, what about a wrong htaccess configuration?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `@web` in backend it loads `domain/backend/web`, but when you call it in frontend - it's `domain/web` or `domain/frontend/web` (I don't know if you have some htaccess rules) so here is your problem.
Image url is with backend.

You just set path like `Url::to('/backend/web/uploads/' . $searchModel->manufacturer_logo)`

or use another way to concatenate `backend` before all.

Also you can set new alias.
In `common/config/bootstrap.php` add this `Yii::setAlias('@backendweb', '/backend');`, so your image url will be:

`Url::to('@backendweb/uploads/' . $searchModel->manufacturer_logo)`

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not work. when I open Image URL then it opens home page of website. I verified that image exists in folder and name is also correct

Comment: give some screenshot

Comment: Do you load your project like - `http://localhost/myprojectname` ? Did you try to create virtual host?

Comment: I use my project URL like http://localhost/myprojectname/backend/web/index.php?r=manufacturers%2Findex and I did not try virtual host